# How to zoom out a bootstrap 4 table

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have a table in bootstrap as

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table>
        ....
    </table>
</div>
```

**Current table on mobile:**

[image]

**need like this one on mobile:**
[image]

So it's a scrollable, what I need to have a zoomed out view of the full table, how can I do this?

Comment: you put the `overflow:scroll` on the div? can you share a minimal, verifiable example which we can check

Comment: @AkberIqbal edited have a look

Comment: `transform: scale(0.6)` on the div with class table-responsive can be used to get what you're looking for, but it wouldn't be very legible

Comment: @AkberIqbal I'm using a plugin of jquery for fixed header your code interepts with that, If I don't change responsiveness of the table is it possible to zoom-out on mobiles? because zoom out on mobile is not working anymore .

Comment: there is a scroll for your page and then there is a scroll on the table-responsive div... the phone will let you zoom out on the outer scroll (the scroll of the page) but wouldn't let you do that for the inner scroll (the scroll on the table-responsive div) - this is what i suspect, but not sure. Let's wait for some experts to share their input here

Answer (score 1):

Try using `zoom:70%;` in your css or higher (make sure it's below 100% though), that should zoom out the page. So try changing your code to this:

```
<div class="table-responsive" style="zoom:70%">...
```

Hope this helps!